# Issue with installing Python Numpy. Shows "Getting requirements to build wheel"

Tags: python, numpy, python-wheel

The code below shows what happens when i install numpy using pip in cmd

```
C:\Users\User>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.25.1.tar.gz (10.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9zchd0sn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9zchd0sn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9zchd0sn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9zchd0sn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9zchd0sn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

And since I cannot install numpy, I am unable to use it, even in Sublime Text and Thonny. I am not entirely sure what I have done to cause this problem.

I already tried updating Python and pip. Im not sure if this is due to multiple numpy's installed or not. If so, how do i locate and uninstall all the packages? Or is there a solution to resolve the problem above?

Comment: try `pip install wheel` before then retry, and tell us the result

Comment: it shows _C:\Users\User>pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (0.41.0)_